# Adding Vectors for Pie Chart

Tags: r

I'm a relative novice in R and am trying to create a pie chart based on two vectors. One vector is composed of a bunch of names like so:

```
Sectors=c("Energy", "Financials", "Cons Disc")
```

The other vector is composed of variable names like so:

```
Weights=c(EWeight, FWeight, CDWeight)
```

Each variable in this vector looks through a .csv file I named "SP_Data" and gives me a numerical output based based on the sum value of every number in the column "% of S&P" based on the criteria of the column "Sector". This looks like the following:

```
EWeight=sum(SP_Data$X..of.S.P[SP_Data$Sector=="Energy"])
```

If I type in "EWeight" in the console, I am able to get the output I want, namely:

```
> EWeight  [1] 5.16
```

But I'm getting an error that I'm not quite sure how to fix when I try and create the pie chart, "Error in rep_len(col, nx) : attempt to replicate non-vector":

```
> pie(Weights, Sectors, main="Breakdown of S&P 500")
```

Does this have something to do with my creation of the second vector? What am I doing wrong here?